# Nginx block root directory

Tags: php, http, nginx, server-side

I have nginx. There is a site in it, the root of the site is /root/SITE
In this SITE directory i have some .php files, and few directories. How can i deny the access ONLY to the .php files in the /root/SITE directory (i mean that in those few directories that are in /root/SITE .php files shouldn't be blocked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're asking that for this server block in your Nginx configuration, only PHP files should be allowed, everything else would get a 404? There's lots of ways to do this (and it would be better to ask in a more Nginx-specific place) - here's just one way:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;    
    root /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Note that using this method, the order of the location blocks is important, since first regex location wins. Also, you can use the case-insensitive location regex operator `~*` if you need to support `.PHP` files for some reason.

Keep in mind this means that image files and CSS files and anything else will be denied. You'll only be able to serve images and stylesheets if you push them through (or create them in) PHP. This also will not allow you to access index.php by browsing to the root of the site with no trailing filename.

I suggest that you may have needs that can be satisfied in a different, better way. You should more fully explain what you are trying to do. What kind of security are you trying to create for your application?

Comment: I have a main_area directory. It's blocked by a password, and i nead a possibility to block the access to the main directory with the site. But main_area directory should be accessable. That's what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't follow you. If you've configured auth_basic for the protected subdirectory "main_area" then that's all you need. There is no further benefit to blocking access to certain file types unless you allow indiscriminate uploads of files from untrusted users to your site.

Comment: Oh, maybe I see -- you only want the "main_area" subdirectory to be accessible? If you're not making anything in the root directory accessible, why not just put auth_basic on the *whole* site?